# Docker supported images

Tags: kaa

Are there any plans to release any docker images on docker hub etc., which we can use to deploy single node/multi node setups?

Currently there is a pretty manual way of creating a docker image:
http://kaaproject.github.io/kaa/docs/v0.10.0/Administration-guide/System-installation/Docker-deployment/

Maybe bake docker image(s) as part of the release process?

Kindly regards

Answer (score 0):

Such questions do not belong to Stack Overflow—you should use Kaa project JIRA for feature requests.

I've opened an issue for you: [KAA-1596](http://jira.kaaproject.org/browse/KAA-1596).